# Custom Parameter for paypal direct payment rest API

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal REST API for making direct payments.
I want to create internal transaction id before initiating the transaction and use that for identifying the transactions from my end.

I am trying to set id using

```
 $payment = new Payment();
 $payment->setId($tId);
```

Paypal is approving the request and payment is getting done but I am not getting this id in response.

Is there any way by which I can send custom parameters to paypal and get them back in response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **custom** variable to pass your custom data, and paypal will return it backto you in post in response.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $totalAmount; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your_paypal_biz_id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/zad_notify.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Image editing"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $paypalReturnUrl; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/payment_error.php?id=<?php echo $sr_no; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $sr_no; ?>" />
```

alternatively you can also pass your id in **notify url** as query string parameter and you will get it back in return url file.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $totalAmount; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="your_paypal_biz_id"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/zad_notify.php?id=5"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Image editing"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $paypalReturnUrl; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/payment_error.php?id=<?php echo $sr_no; ?>"/>
```

Hope this help to you, :)

Comment: This I know , but I am unable to find option to set custom in resp API using their sdk

Comment: Unfortunately, the REST API is still pretty far behind the classic API's with all of the features they provide. To my knowledge, custome simply aren't included in the REST API yet.

That said, if you have IPN configured in your PayPal account profile the REST API calls should still trigger them. It's just that you can't override the value there with a custom one using notify like you're talking about.

The classic API's aren't going away, though. You can still use them just fine. Though I am searching for you on web and will let you know if I found something concrete for you :)

Comment: Do you know how to set the custom parameter in the classic API?